# Attempting to display an image URL within an SVG tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I am using Codepen.io for this, i.e.:

HTML:

```
<h1>SVG Image Example</h1>

<svg  version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
</svg>
```

JS:

```
var svgimg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','image');
svgimg.setAttribute('height','50');
svgimg.setAttribute('width','50');
svgimg.setAttribute('xlink:href', 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000532546226/dbe5f0727b69487016ffd67a6689e75a.jpeg');
svgimg.setAttribute('x','50');
svgimg.setAttribute('y','50');
$('svg').append(svgimg);
```

Unfortunately, the image URL I have in the code above is not displaying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SVG native attributes (not including xlink:href) do not share the SVG namespace;

You should be using like this

```
svgimg.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href' ,'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/SVG_logo.svg');
```

instead of **svgimg.setAttribute()**

Here is a [DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/vsd7rf76/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are setting the image dynamically, you have to use **`domElement.setAttributeNS()`**. Normally, SVG native attributes do not share the SVG namespace, which is why the size and position attributes can be set with **`domElement.setAttribute()`**, however, the `xlink:href` attribute is one exception so we need to be explicit about setting the namespace.

```
svgimg.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000532546226/dbe5f0727b69487016ffd67a6689e75a.jpeg');
```